# reading file line by line in an infinite loop until break

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to implement an infinite loop bash script for reading in a file, doing something and check counter condition, when counter condition reaches 0 it breaks out of the infinite loop. I've tried several iteration and none has worked for me. Pseudo-code would be something line this..

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=10
while true
do
  read host from file
  ping -c 1 host > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    (($counter+1))
    do_something_to_the_host
  else
    (($counter-1))
    if [ $counter -eq 0 ]
    then
      break # this breaks out of the while true infinite loop
    fi
  fi
done
```

Can anyone show me how to implement something like the above in bash please?

As always, thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want an infinite loop? Does your file have an infinite list of hosts? Are you trying to ping the host and if it does not respond after 10 tries, then you move on to the next host?

Comment: Hi, I want the loop to be infinite because I want the reading in of the file to be repeated until the counter check condition equals 0. There might be a better way to do what I want to do, but that is what I thought would be the simplest, I could be wrong. I'm open to guidance and suggestions.

Comment: what happens when you get to the end of the file?

Comment: I want the loop to keep repeating reading in the file, the counter is the condition that triggers the break out from the infinite loop.

Comment: Could you post _bash script_ examples that didn't work for you? What is the purpose of the _counter_? Is it just to get out of the loop? Is it to somehow limit the script not to ping all the hosts from the file?

Comment: I haven't been able to write the bash script as I wanted as explained, the skeleton of the script is as shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two nested loops: an outer infinite loop, and an inner loop that reads each line from the input file. `break` takes a numerical argument to specify how many loops to break out of.

```
counter=10
while true
do
  while read host
  do
    ping -c 1 host > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      (($counter+=1))
      do_something_to_the_host
    else
      (($counter-=1))
      if [ $counter -eq 0 ]
      then
        break 2
      fi
    fi
  done < file
done
```

Comment: You're not *changing* the value of the counter

Comment: Hi Glenn, Didn't see your reply and I ended up writing the identical, but I'm glad I did now and was able to check my scripts with yours. THANK YOU!